# Using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE as a select field

Tags: sql, mariadb

As a curiosity question, is there a way to use an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement as a subquery?

The following example throws an error:

```sql
SELECT 1, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT 2"
```

Expected result: 1, 2

I've tried a few tricks, but it doesn't seem possible.

Thank you for any idea!

Comment: It's this line in the docs that (try to ) says something: "Limitations: subselects and stored function calls are not supported as a prepare source."  (see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/ )

Comment: @Luuk the given example for subselect is EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (SELECT 'SELECT * FROM t1') which is not my issue

Comment: Ok, using EXECUTE as a sub-query just wont work, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=97df5d305cc6306e06bebf6ebb35a6d9   (It has not much to do with IMMEDIATE, which is only available on MariaDB)

Comment: As a curiosity question :), why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Nick pentesting !

Comment: Gotcha. I think you're pretty safe on this one